# How can i get :params from location?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to implement wide spread pattern mywebsite/en/welcome. In this case i have to modify all my for including actual param :lang into their prop 'to'. Without this implementation i couldn't know current language. So, i use handleLocationChange to spread curent :lang to all my components. But i receive location prop which include only current path and query. How can i receive curent :lang param too ?
p.s. i would like to avoid all of this but AFAIK react-router doesn't support relative links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `<Route>`'s component is rendered, it is passed a `params` prop which you can use to access the `lang` parsed from the URL. If you need access to this from a child component you will have to pass it as a prop to that component.

```
<Route path=':lang/my-page' component={MyPage} />

const MyPage = (props) => {
  const { lang } = props.params
  return (
    <div>This page's language is: {lang} </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank u for ur answer. I did in a similar way. I pass routeParams through context to children but sinse i use mobx to manage my app state i get error "MobX Provider: Provided store 'location' has changed. Please avoid replacing stores as the change might not propagate to all children". I think libraries like redux-react-router or mobx-react-router were created to solve this issue. But they only react to browser history changes. The key point of my issue is how to retrive routeParams from history.

Though, i'll try to implement ur suggestion

Comment: unfortunately if i transfer props.params to context children don't receive fresh params if url changed. So, i decided to use query from location which is provided by browser history